# How to check if debug is true and can I use it for my own code?

Tags: debug, wp-debug

I'm needing to debug one of my themes and I want to be able to switch on a debug mode so I can output more information or switch off debug mode and not see any information.

I noticed there is a debug variable defined in wp_config.php. I can easily set this to true or false. Is it OK to use this variable for my own debugging purposes or should I create my own?

Also, how do I check for if debug is true? My PHP is a bit rusty. Is this correct:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

if ($WP_DEBUG) {
   // do something
}
```

My question is different.

Comment: Why cant you install your theme on a local instance and leave debug equal to true?   Its not a good idea to leave debug true on a live site.

Comment: @Darth_Vader It's much easier for me to debug on the remote site right now. At a later time I might setup a local install. But as you confirmed, it's not a good idea to leave debug set to true on a live site. So I want to enable it briefly to inspect any errors and then turn it off quickly if I have to. Local installs are unfortunately different than remote.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee not quite the same question. they mention log files and different variables than I am asking about.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest doing this but if you do you should do a redirect before enabling debug

Comment: WP_DEBUG is defined as a constant, not as a variable, to check it you should do `if ( WP_DEBUG )` (without the $ symbol). Apart from that, the linked question by @Howdy_McGee seems what you need to switch on/off debug programmatically.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

PHP constants don't have the leading `$`. Strictly, this isn't WordPress, but since there isn't a Core `is_debug()` function that I am aware of, what you want is:

```
if (defined('WP_DEBUG') && true === WP_DEBUG) {
   echo 'd00d';
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be good to add if_logged_in so this wont be visible to someone who doesn't need to see it?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't run it on a live site at all. If I did, displaying it only for admins is a pretty good compromise.

Comment: Is WP_DEBUG defined by default? It's defined in my wp_config.php but I've modified it.

Comment: It's is defined in a file meant to be edited. I don't know that I'd trust it to be defined.

Comment: I'm using `if ( WP_DEBUG ) {  }` and it works just fine...

Comment: @dev_masta aye, but remember, soon PHP will completely deprecate the check for uninstantiated objects. The extra check will be mandatory in the near future; currently it just throws a warning, but remember: today, a warning; tomorrow, a deprecation notice; and finally, the functionality will be removed and it will throw an error and die/panic/exit (usually with a cryptic message). The solution above has the merit of being future-proof!

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn, but of course, I completely agree. My comment is now more than 7 years old and I wouldn't do the same today. Check if the constant is defined and then check it's value, that's the way to go.